# how to animate li elements one after another

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have ul and want to animate li elements like they move from bottom to up and one after anther or one by one

```
        <ul class="answers">
    <li class="answer"><a href="#" class="expand">click</a>
<p>adasdanvljskljfklsdklfsdjfkljsdkljfklsdjklfjskldjfklsdjklfjsdkfjksjdklfjs;dfl;sdkf
    fsdfsdfsdfsfhowerjweklfjifjvjdfioverjgfioqwopiropqieopki</p>
   </li>
    <li class="answer"><a href="#" class="expand">click</a>
<p>adasdanvljskljfklsdklfsdjfkljsdkljfklsdjklfjskldjfklsdjklfjsdkfjksjdklfjs;dfl;sdkf
    fsdfsdfsdfsfhowerjweklfjifjvjdfioverjgfioqwopiropqieopki</p>
   </li>

  <li class="answer"><a href="#" class="expand">click</a>
<p>adasdanvljskljfklsdklfsdjfkljsdkljfklsdjklfjskldjfklsdjklfjsdkfjksjdklfjs;dfl;sdkf
    fsdfsdfsdfsfhowerjweklfjifjvjdfioverjgfioqwopiropqieopki</p>
  </li>

   <li class="answer"><a href="#" class="expand">click</a>
<p>adasdanvljskljfklsdklfsdjfkljsdkljfklsdjklfjskldjfklsdjklfjsdkfjksjdklfjs;dfl;sdkf
    fsdfsdfsdfsfhowerjweklfjifjvjdfioverjgfioqwopiropqieopki</p>
   </li>

    </ul>

      ul{list-style:none;}
       li{ width:100%; height:20px; overflow:hidden; position:relative; top:9999999999999px;}

   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('.answer').animate({
        top:"0px"
        },5000);
       });
```

how can i do that

Comment: If that's just some gibberish in the code, it's not helpful at all.

Comment: no its a different thing

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you don't have any errors in your code elsewhere.

Something like this should work

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   var delay-time = 600;

   $('.answer').each(function() {

       $(this).delay(delay-time).animate({top:"0px"},5000);

       delay-time += 600;

   });

});
```

This code will loop through each of the `.answer` elements. The delay will be increased for each one, which will make it so they don't all animate at the same time, but will animate one after the other. Adjust the delay time to however many milliseconds works best for you.